# MySQL subquery to delete rows

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble executing a subquery in order to delete some specific rows in my application. Here's my wrong SQL:

```
   delete from player_news_items 
     where id IN 
      (select id from player_news_items 
      where player_id NOT IN (select id from players));
```

What's the right way to write this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you cannot refer to the table being modified in an `update` or `delete`, unless you use a `join`.  However, I think you might just want this:

```
delete pni
    from player_news_items pni
    where player_id NOT IN (select id from players));
```

As a note, I would advice writing this with `not exists`:

```
delete pni
    from player_news_items pni
    where not exists (select 1 from players p where p.player_id = pni.player_id);
```

Comment: Not that I disagree, but why would the second form be a more preferred way of writing the query?  The first form is more concise and *looks* like it should be faster.

Comment: As a new guy, I would like to ask then is there a performance difference between NOT IN and EXISTS? Sure, @zebediah49 it _looks_ faster, but _is it_ faster?

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . In some databases, `not exists` is more efficient than `not in`.  More importantly, if `players.id` is ever `NULL`, then the first version will *never* return any values.  `Not exists` actually handles `NULL`s more intuitively than `NOT IN`.